# Hide/Show a div in a list

Tags: javascript, html

I have a list with an arbitrary number of items. Each item has a number of actions that can be done onto it. I want to display those actions in a div that appears when the user clicks a link associated with the specific list item.

I have tried the following code but when I click the link it just shows the first hidden div and not the hidden div associated with the link.

```
<script language="javascript"> 
function toggleOptions() {
        var ele = this;
        var text = this.parentNode.getElementsByClassName("displayOptions");


    if(ele.style.display == "block") {
        ele.style.display = "none";
    text.innerHTML = "TESTING";
    }
    else {
    ele.style.display = "block";
    text.innerHTML = "Hide GPS";
    }
}
```

HERE IS THE HTML. The list could be endless though, this is just an excerpt of the list.

```
     <a href="javascript:toggleOptions();">
        ITEM 1 OPTIONS
     </a>
      <div class="toggleOptions" style="display: none">
        ITEM 1 OPTIONS
     </div>

     <a href="javascript:toggleOptions();">
        ITEM 2 OPTIONS
     </a>
     <div class="toggleOptions" style="display: none">
        ITEM 2 OPTIONS
     </div>

     <a href="javascript:toggleOptions();">
        ITEM 3 OPTIONS
     </a>
      <div class="toggleOptions" style="display: none">
        ITEM 2 OPTIONS
     </div>
```

Comment: Can you show us what the HTML looks like?

Comment: check if this is really what you want **document.getElementById(".toggleOptions");** .. this looks for me as you want to get a element with class toggleOptions... otherwise use document.getElementsByClass('toggleOptions') but this will always be an array so you have to select which one you want

Comment: Stegrex, I just updated my code with the HTML. Mik, I do want to use classes and I have tried it with the ClassName but it did not show/hide any of the hidden divs.

Comment: You can't use IDs more than once in a DOM, but you're using `id="toggleOptions"` three times... (invalid!)

Comment: Raudberdaniel, Yes I understand but I just wanted to demonstrate what the final product should look like. If you try the code as is, ITEM 1 OPTIONS will display no matter what ITEM you click.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

put another div or something around each group: ... put the toggleOptions() function to onclick and pass the href a # so that it is not empty... pass toggleOptions(this) to know which element is clicked

```
<div>
    <a href="#" onclick="toggleOptions(this);" style="display:block;">
        SHOW
     </a>
      <div class="toggleOptions" style="display: none">
        ITEM 1 OPTIONS
     </div>
</div>
<div>
    <a href="#" onclick="toggleOptions(this);" style="display:block;">
        SHOW
     </a>
      <div class="toggleOptions" style="display: none">
        ITEM 2 OPTIONS
     </div>
</div>
<div>
    <a href="#" onclick="toggleOptions(this);" style="display:block;">
        SHOW
     </a>
      <div class="toggleOptions" style="display: none">
        ITEM 3 OPTIONS
     </div>
</div>​
```

try with this here http://jsfiddle.net/YE6XZ/1/

```
function toggleOptions(e) {
    var ele = e;
    var text = e.parentElement.querySelector('.toggleOptions')

if(text.style.display == "none") {
    //ele.style.display = "none";
    text.style.display = "block";
    text.innerHTML = "TESTING";
    ele.innerHTML = "hide";
}
else {
    text.style.display = "none";
    //text.innerHTML = "Hide GPS";
    ele.innerHTML = "show";
}

return false;
```

}

Comment: Mik I updated the initial code with your suggested changes. It still doesnt seem to be working.

Comment: did you try the new version..? you can check it out in the jsfiddle link

Comment: Mik, Nice man! However, how do I get the link to stay displayed when the toggleOptions div is displayed? Cause I would like to use the link to show/hide the toggleOptions div.

Comment: Mik, actually how can I display the content within the displayOptions div? For example, when you click show, "ITEM OPTIONS 1" should appear.

Comment: but actually have a look at jquery .... this things are much easier with jquery ... for example it provides a toggleClass function so you dont need to check if the element is hidden or not . aso

Answer (score 0):

`.toggleOptions` is not a valid `id` DOM attribute value. Are you trying to get an element by its className? Then you should use [`getElementsByClassName`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/document.getElementsByClassName) instead, or remove the leading dot in the literal.